# Maui Blazor Error XFC0000 Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace:[Project name]:Main

Tags: xaml, maui-blazor

This error suddenly came into my project and prevents me to build it.
Erp is the name of the project.
I am building same project in other machine with no problem, and I can't see any difference.
Nuget packages are all installed correctly.
Error complains from line 10 of MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Erp"
             x:Class="Erp.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">

    <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>

</ContentPage>
```

Main.razor also looks ok:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Main).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally discovered a bug, I left a @ character alone inside a div and this resulted in error XFC0000:

```
    <div class="Errs">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation"></i>
        @
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved
If copying the code from a previously created project check the app name after using the keyword and code the routing well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).